# Use JFrame (or external equivelant) on Android

Tags: java, android, swing, jframe

I'm working on a small 2D tile-based game prototype for Android in Java. Unfortunately, I don't understand Android nearly as well as straight Java, and JFrame-based methods are perfect for what I'm trying to do. I've already done some research, and the general consensus is that it's impossible... But JFrame is exactly what I need. Is there any way at all to use it, or at least an external library that recreates it's functionality?

Comment: *"..or at least an external library that recreates it's functionality?"*  Given `JFrame` does some things that are not appropriate to a tablet/phone UI, I'd say you're completely out of luck!  What functionality, specifically and exactly, do you wish to see in the Android component?

Comment: I'm trying to make a tile-based 2D game, and I've already done that kind of thing with JFrame. With Android, though, I can't quite get it. It's mostly the rendering style, not really the window... Just the way it's used within the window is what I need, not the window itself

Answer (score 1):

In a word -- no, you can't use any Swing component related classes whatsoever with your Android application as they are structured and rendered completely differently. You can only use your model classes if they are well behaved, and you'll of course have to learn the Android library/platform.

Comment: Even an external library would be fine... It's just that I need that functionality, and the platform isn't really negotiable. Even something that lets me emulate that same functionality within Android's capabilities would be more than acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely clear there... The game I'm working on is a 2D tile-based game, which from what I've seen will be a pain with Android's base system stuff.

Comment: Dang... I really need some of the stuff from JFrame. Guess I'll have to switch to a different engine.